# assembler set up function dependent on variable

Tags: assembly, arm, 32-bit, beagleboneblack

So I am writing an assembly program where I set a variable to *one*, *two* or *three* and then dependent on that variable the right function should be used in the further program.

As an example if the value is *one* the function should look like this:

```
FUNC:
    ADD   r2, r3, 6
    WBS   r30.t1
    SUB   r3, r3, 1
```

Or if the value is *two*:

```
FUNC:
    ADD   r2, r4, 5
    SUB   r4, r4, 2
```

So there should be no difference to the main-loop depending on which function is really called.

How can i configure a assembly-label to run another predifened routine?

Comment: how do you do it in any other language, if variable then functino else if then function, and so on.  just do that here. or write a simple function in a high level language compile it and see what the compiler produces.  basically  you need to compare and jump

Comment: @dwelch: ok simple but not efficient for my purpose..  These functions will be called very frequently and i only have to initialize them to a dedicated routine and then leave them just as they are. They will be changed exactly once. I wondered if there is no better solution.

Comment: You mean a function pointer? Or self modifying code.

Comment: Can't you just use a function pointer (i.e. indirect branch)?

Comment: you still have to do some flavor of if then else, which you can learn by watching how a compiler does it and then look up the instructions.  you dont have a choice either dont have a conditional execution path or have a conditional execution path.  make up your mind

Comment: if you want this to behave/feel like a function pointer in a high level language then you just setup an address to the function outside the main loop since you dont want the conditional there and branch to that pre-computed function.  This is a runtime thing though based on your description so you cannot do it by label, label is a compile time thing, the conditional code can use the label to determine the address, then you use the address be it in a register or a memory location that you load into a register then use bx or ldr pc,...

Answer (score 1):

Is this "variable" an assemble-time constant?  If so, then use assembler macros rather than instructions that will execute at runtime.

If not, but it changes extremely infrequently, self-modifying code could work.  (i.e. copy the appropriate machine code into a buffer labelled `FUNC` when it changes, so you don't have to check the variable before every call).

It's not really *self* modifying code, though, unless "self" means the whole program.  It's more like a special-purpose JIT compiler.

---

If neither of these things are true, then you obviously have to write asm that depends on the value of your variable somehow.  Conditional branches, an indirect jump / call, or predicated execution are the main choices.

Remember that each assembly instruction just turns into some bytes of machine code.  You can only interact with runtime "variables" using asm instructions, not assembler directives or anything "magic" like you seem to be hoping for.

Comment: Addendum to the code-modification case: if the function in question is only called from one or two places then it's probably simpler and more efficient to just patch the branch offset of the calling instruction, rather than rewriting the whole code of the callee.